# Setting a shortcut for setting selected text's font in OneNote

Tags: ms-office, office365, onenote

I have been taking notes in OneNote as I listen to classes etc. and it helps to represent code differently using Courier New etc. Having to keep doing it using main menu is getting to be very painful.

**Is there anyway to set a shortcut for setting selected text's font to say Courier New etc.?**

Note : I tried using Onetastic macros but they are extremely slow and makes onenote unresponsive for a ~10 secs or so, and moreover even that doesn't have a keyboard shortcut option.

I would be surprised that OneNote which is heavily note taking tool doesn't have anyway to customize keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a shortcut to the Font box to the OneNote Window frame (click the dropdown to select Customize Quick Access Toolbar, then add the Font command under all commands).  This adds a number to the Font shortcut box - on my machine 3 - so the Home Tab doesn't need to open on the ribbon, nor do I need the (capital) FF to select the Font chooser on the home tab.
So my shortcut would now be ALT 3, cou to select Courier New.

Alternately:
ALT+ H, FF, then the cou  will change the font to Courier (open the Home tab, Font Selector, then selects Courier New).  But selecting capital FF there is a pain.

One optimization you could make would be to copy the Courier New font to be named "ff.ttf"  using TTX or FontForge or similar tools.  Then the keys would be 
ALT+ H , FF, ff

But adding to the QAT is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ... though not perfect - I can live with this.